# Organizing Projects within Solution and avoiding duplicate code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-duplication

I'm attempting to learn VS/C#/Sql Server by developing a small application. I'm having a lot of success (and excitement) getting the results I want, but after stepping back I realize I'm programming in more of a linear way (from my mainframe background) and not taking advantage of OOP. I'm also finding myself duplicating code.

My 'solution' within VS consists of the following 'projects' so far (I'm creating each project as a 'console application' to keep things simple):

- Project 1: Create Master Datefile (DB) by generating dates for the year (will be run yearly)
- Project 2: Convert historical Data (from an Excel (CSV) file into multiple tables of DB (this process will be run randomly will be run as new companies are signed up)
- Project 3: Update DB table via Excel (CSV) input (also run randomly)
- Project 4: Schedule availability for multiple companies (routine process run weekly)

My current dilemna is twofold:
1) I'm unsure how to share code among the different projects in my solution
- for projects 2 through 4, I'm soliciting user input for company ID and other parameters. How do I share this code among the projects? Would I create a class for something like 'console input' and reference it to each?
2) I'm unsure if I'm splitting my tasks out correctly among projects.
- since these are all processes that run independently, the only way to design this is to split them among diffferent projects...right?

Any tips on organizing within the VS environment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create class librarys with your objects (entitys) and reuse in your application. For example:

1 Project: Master_Datefile_Objects = entitys and business intelligence

1.1 Project: Master_Datefile_Forms or any other (Console, Service, etc);

Separate in folders your entitys and the classes that controller your entitys.

For example:

folder: Manager (Find your entitys in a database and all logic of your project)

//Internal is accessible only in the current project

```
internal class MyClass_Student_Manager
{
  public MyClass_Student_Model returnStudent(int ID)
  {
    return (your_Query_In_YourDataBase(ID));
  }
}
```

folder: model

```
public class MyClass_Student_Model
{
   public int ID {get; set;}

   public string name {get; set;}
}
```

folder: facade

This class, will access your methods of managers

```
public class myProject_Facade
{
   public MyClass_Student_Model returnStudent(int ID)
  {
    return new MyClass_Student_Manager().returnStudent(ID);
  }
}
```

And in your other project (Master_Datefile_Forms) you go call the methods of facade referencing your project Master_Datefile_Objects.

This is a Example. When you want reuse MyClass_Student and your logic, you can import the project in others solutions.

Comment: thanks Sergio - Class libraries is something I'll be reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning Visual Studio, C#, and SQL. I've found my favorite pattern seems to be using the Three-Layer Application pattern.

The first layer consists of the data layer. All it does is interface with your database or other data sources and make that data available and usable by the layers above it. The second layer consists of the service layer. It handles the business logic. The third layer consists of the presentation layer, with the sole purpose is user interaction.

What has worked for me is to create a solution that includes one project for each layer. This helps separate concerns and since each project is included in the same solution, they can reference each other. Having said that, for larger projects, I've found that breaking related code into separate folders in a project is helpful.

Hope this helps, it's my first Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Yeah - this helps a lot. However, I'm still confused about the basics. From what I understand, you can only have one 'Main' program within a project (within a solution). As you can see from my question - I currently have 4 (with more to come) what I call 'batch' programs (left over from my legacy systems background) that need to run at different times. Wouldn't this require a 'project' (within a 'solution') for each? And all of them would be sharing classes, properties, and methods(?)

Comment: Yes, this is the way most of my projects work. Each layer is it's own project and each project layer can inherit from the layer below. This is particularly useful when I want to change one layer's implementation. For example, if you wanted to change the presentation layer to a web-based layer, you don't have to factor any of the lower level logic, only changing console output ot web output.